# Use default proxysettings with httplib

Tags: python, proxy, tunnel, httplib

Is there a way to use the system's default proxy to setup a httptunnel with `httplib(2)`(without having to provide the info and credentials)?

I've had a look at `urllib2.ProxyHandler` and that seems to do everything I want. But if I google for an httplib alternative I always have to provide the server and port.

```
class urllib2.ProxyHandler([proxies])

Cause requests to go through a proxy. If proxies is given, it must be a dictionary mapping protocol names to URLs of proxies. 
The default is to read the list of proxies from the environment variables <protocol>_proxy. 
If no proxy environment variables are set, then in a Windows environment proxy settings are obtained from the registry’s Internet Settings section, and in a Mac OS X environment proxy information is retrieved from the OS X System Configuration Framework. 
To disable autodetected proxy pass an empty dictionary.`
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently httplib and urllib2 are somewhat interchangeable

```
remote_addr = {"host": host, "port": port}

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler()
proxy_opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(proxy_opener)

http_opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
params = urllib.urlencode({"data": 'some data'})
url = "http://{host}:{port}".format(host=remote_addr['host'], port=remote_addr['port'])
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
request = urllib2.Request(url, params, headers)
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = http_opener.open(request)
```